# Django QuerySet aggregate based on field value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My model is as follows:

```
class AssetIdentifications(models.Model):  
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, editable=False, null=False)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(
        "Entity", db_constraint=False, null=False,
    )
    asset = models.ForeignKey(
        "Asset", db_constraint=False, null=False
    )
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        null=False,
    )
    vendor = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, null=False
    )
    software = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, null=False
    )
    version = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, null=False
    )
```

I want to get a queryset that is grouped based on unique values of `vendor`. The result should look something like this:

```
{"vendor1": [\<list of AssetIdentifications\>], "vendor2": [\<list of AssetIdentifications\>] ...}
```

Is this possible with a `group_by` or `aggregate` function (I haven't found something like this in the docs)? Or would I have to iterate through the queryset I obtain just through filtering like `AssetIdentifications.objects.filter(entity=e)`

Comment: If you use a `ForeignKey` toa `Vendor` model, then this is a lot easier.

Comment: unfortunately there is no Vendor model, the data for this table does not come from django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`groupby(…)` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) of the [**`itertools`** module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

result = {
    k: list(vs)
    for k, vs in
    groupby(AssetIdentifications.objects.order_by('vendor'), attrgetter('vendor'))
}
```

Here `result` is a dictionary that maps the `vendor`s on a list of `AssetIndentification` objects.